# Подскажите небольшие open source проекты для обучения

Tags: java, python, c, opensource

Попроще, чтобы не утонуть в коде. Интересуют языки Java, C, Python. Если с GUI то предпочтительно GTK+.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно много. Например, на Python: Gajim (xmpp-клиент на GTK+), JabbIM (xmpp-клиент на Qt), Ubuntu Software Center (Для Linux, GTK+), ubuntu-tweak, bleachbit, список можно продолжать бесконечно.